# unimplemented pure virtual method

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a pure method from a class Algorithm to a class BasicAlgo like this :

```
class Algorithm
{
    public:
        virtual void solve() = 0;
};

class BasicAlgo : public Algorithm
{
    public:
         void solve() { };
};

Algorithm a = BasicAlgo();
a.solve();
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
variable type 'Algorithm' is an abstract class
    Algorithm a = BasicAlgo();
              ^
unimplemented pure virtual method 'solve' in 'Algorithm'
            virtual void solve() = 0;
```

After lots of time on Stackoverflow looking for a solution, I still don't really understand why there is an error. To me `a.solve()` is `BasicAlgo::solve` witch is well implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ isn't Java.

```
Algorithm a = BasicAlgo();
```

The above attempts to define an **object** of type `Algorithm` by copy initializing it from a `BasicAlgo`. Even if it was to work (which it won't in this case, due to the pure virtual function that prohibits instantiating `Algorithm` objects), you would just [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) your `BasicAlgo` object into an `Algorithm`.

For your purposes, you need a pointer or reference, like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> a = std::make_unique<BasicAlgo>();
a->solve();
```

Comment: @GuillaumeWuip, You're welcome. I recommend you try to put your Java knowledge aside and approach c++ as a novice programmer would. They share some keywords, and are both "curly braces" languages, but that's where the similarity ends. They deal in completely different idioms.

Comment: That's what my teacher is telling too. It's hard sometimes. C++ has a lot of this kind of extremely powerful features

Comment: @GuillaumeWuip, it does indeed. But it can be counter intuitive when we attempt and apply expectations from Java. (I'm not trying to beat on Java, it's just a different beast). [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) has some of the best book recommendations, which I feel are a necessity for those learning c++.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for this link @StoryTeller

Answer (score 1):

`Algorithm a = BasicAlgo();` doesn't allow for polymorphic behaviour - in fact, if the class wasn't abstract, you'd encounter [*slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

You can use `std::unique_ptr` to allow for inheritance polymorphism:

```
std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> a = std::make_unique<BasicAlgo>();
```